# Simple introduction to linear models in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, references, lm

It was hard for me to understand linear models in R. There are a lot of documents for the case, but many of them are technical manuals rather than teaching the concept.

I found [this article](http://users.monash.edu.au/~murray/stats/BIO4200/LinearModels.pdf) really simple and instructive, I hope it would be useful for the other people who have the same problem.

Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: What you have supplied is a chapter from a book. Prescinding from the question of whether you have violated copyright by posting it, it would at least be a courtesy to the author to supply a citation.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of time looking through `R` manuals. The best one that I've seen is Grant Farnsworth's "Econometrics in `R`". Check it out: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf. It's concise, but quickly covers a broad range of topics. The article you found looks good too!

Answer (score 0):

1. Hamilton, "[Low-Tech Causal Modeling](http://pubpages.unh.edu/~lch/causal2.pdf)", 2008
2. Diez et al., "Introduction to linear regression" ch. 11 in *[OpenIntro Stats](http://www.openintro.org/stat/)*,  2nd ed., 2012
3. Gelman and Hill, ch. 3-4 in *[Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)*, 2007
4. McIntosh, “[Doing” Applied Econometrics](http://courses.cals.uidaho.edu/aers/agecon525/sp2010/Lecture21DoingAppliedEconometrics.pdf)”, c. 2010

That's probably a bit more than a hundred pages, with roughly half the content from Gelman and Hill, who use R. I realize the book is not free, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another resource.  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf It is targeted at the fundamentals of using R for Regression and ANOVA.  Both single variable regression, multivariate regression, single factor and multifactor ANOVA are discussed.   This was the last version 2002 before the author published a book with this as a subset "Linear Models with R" (very good, by the way IMO)